# How to display cart items detail in Django template

Tags: python, django

I want to display my cart information in detail (all items and their details as well) on Django template but I don't know how.

views.py

```
def cart(request):
    context={'cart': Cart.objects.filter(is_paid=False)}
    return render(request, 'cart.html',context)
```

models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    is_paid=models.BooleanField(default=False)

class CartItems(models.Model):
    cart=models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True)
    color_variant=models.ForeignKey(ColorVariant, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    size_variant=models.ForeignKey(SizeVariant, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

cart.html

```
{% if cart %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in cart %}
            <td class="product__cart__item">
                <div class="product__cart__item__pic">
                    <img src="{% static "img/shopping-cart/cart-1.jpg" %}" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="product__cart__item__text">
                    <h6>{{ item.product.name }}</h6>
                    <h5>98</h5>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="quantity__item">
                <div class="quantity">
                    <div class="pro-qty-2">
                        <input type="text" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="cart__price">$ 30.00</td>
            <td class="cart__close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of your current code? And also give us other objects because we don't see their info (e.g. Product).

Comment: `cart` is not iterable. You have to loop for items. Try `{% for item in cart.item_set.all %}`

Comment: @EzonZhao It is, `'cart': Cart.objects.filter(is_paid=False)` is in context that is passed in HTML

Comment: @BokiX thanks for pointing out. Then it is not obvious what you really want. Maybe a nested loop? `{% for cart_x in cart %}{% for item in cart_x.item_set.all %}`

Comment: can you please print cart object after filter ?